# I simply want to send shopping cart to email in photocrati wp theme

Tags: jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming, shopping-cart, email

I'm using a Photocrati WordPress theme which has only one checkout process which redirects to PayPal. I created a new button but I need it to call a different action that will send the contents of the shopping cart to a specific email and redirect the user to a thank you page WITHOUT a payment gateway such as PayPal. I am lost as to how to get this done even though I successfully created the button but that's it. It seems very simple since all the values are there, any help or direction will be greatly appreciated. Photocrati Themes use a combination of jQuery and php for the shopping cart. The shopping cart page is a WordPress Template page file but here is the sendcart.php (action file being called from the template page file):

```
define('ABSPATH', dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))).'/');
include_once(ABSPATH.'wp-config.php');
include_once(ABSPATH.'wp-load.php');
include_once(ABSPATH.'wp-includes/wp-db.php');
global $wpdb;

// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
$req .= "&$key=$value";
}

// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

// assign posted variables to local variables
$firstName = $_POST['first_name'];
$lastName = $_POST['last_name'];
$email = $_POST['payer_email'];

if (!$fp) {
// HTTP ERROR
} else {
fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
while (!feof($fp)) {
$res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
// check the payment_status is Completed
// check that txn_id has not been previously processed
// check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
// check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
// process payment
}
else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
// log for manual investigation
}
}
fclose ($fp);
}

$admin_info = get_userdata(1);
$admineaddr = get_option('admin_email');

if (isset($admin_info->user_email) && $admin_info->user_email != null)
{
    $admineaddr = $admin_info->user_email;
}

// Send thank you email/receipt
$p_date = date("M d, Y");
$subject = "Thank you for your purchase!";
$message = "Thank you for your purchase! A notification will be sent to you by PayPal with the transaction details.";
$headers = "From: ".$admineaddr."\r\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: ".$admineaddr."\r\n";

mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers);


$subject2 = "New Sale";
$message2 = "A new sale has been made:
Name: ".$firstName." ".$lastName."
Email: ".$email."";                         
$headers2 = "From: ".$admineaddr."\r\n";
$headers2 .= "Return-Path: ".$admineaddr."\r\n";

mail($admineaddr, $subject2, $message2, $headers2);

/* IMPORTANT! This code empties the entire cart! */
unset($_SESSION['cart']);
unset($_SESSION['cart_qty']);
?>
```

Please help!! 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I'd chime in because I work at Photocrati - we're working on NextGEN Gallery Pro which will be seamlessly integrated into Photocrati 5.  The future update will include an eCommerce system with a lot more capabilities, including multiple payment options.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but unfortunately, this is a pressing need for now, I can't wait for the future update to get this done. If you have a short-term solution for me I'll be more than happy to entertain it.

Comment: We have heard from other customers that FotoMoto works with the theme.